# kotlin: wrong inference of nullability in function reference?

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

i want to choose a validation function for a nullable string:

```
val aString: String? = ...
val validation
       //  : KFunction1<CharSequence?, Boolean>
           = if (...) Objects::isNull else StringUtils::isNotBlank
```

`isNotBlank` is from apache commons. it takes string and returns bool.

when i uncomment explicit type declaration all is good. but when there is no explicit type declared, it infers `KFunction1<CharSequence, Boolean>` so parameter cannot be null. why?

Comment: You can also use String::isNotBlank in kotlin > 1.2.0

Comment: I dont understand your problem well. Why dont u just use aString.isNullOrEmpty() from kotlin natively?

Comment: using `String::isNullOrEmpty` instead of `StringUtils::isNotBlank` produces the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> This is intended behavior. The type to the left of `::` is actually the type of the instance you're going to pass to the reference as the first argument, so type inference uses it as the first argument to `KFunction1`.
>
> If you'd like a reference to be callable on `StringUtils?` objects, use `StringUtils?::isNotBlank`, but the `StringUtils::isNotBlank` reference will only accept non-null `StringUtils` objects.

[Reference](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23641)

Comment: In your issue you used `String::isNotBlank`, which is a Kotlin function `CharSequence.isNotBlank(): Boolean`. Note no question mark there. The OP asks about a Java method `StringUtils.isNotBlank` .

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the issue because Kotlin correctly infers a non-null receiver for `String::isNotBlank`.

Comment: The rationale for the other method was not to pull in another dependency. `String::isNullOrBlank` seems to be a better fit.

Comment: Updated with real reason